# ADF Data Flow creates empty file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have setup a very basic data transformation using a "Data flow". I'm taking in a CSV file and modifying one of the columns and writing to a new CSV file in an "output" directory. I noticed that after the pipeline runs not only does it create the output folder but it also creates and empty file with the same name as the output folder.

Did I setup something wrong or is this empty file normal?

Sink Settings

[Sink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXkU9.png)

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqboR.png)

[Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skUVM.png)

[Optimize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK0P0.png)

[Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijnpr.png)

Thank you,

Scott

Comment: Can you show us the setting of your sink?

Comment: I've adding my sink settings to post as images. Thanks for looking @SteveZhao

Comment: Your setting is correct. This seems a bug. You can connect to Azure support.

Comment: Thank you @SteveZhao

Comment: @Scott  Is the error solved now? when using data flow, we can't  specify the output file name. And before debug the pipeline, please check the source data preview, other actives and sink out data preview. If the data are not empty, then output should not be empty.

Comment: @LeonYue - There isn't really an error just an empty file, this seems to match the folder name of where the data is being processed. It does not cause any issues I'm just not sure why it gets created.